# Metric (tensor?) on a cylinder with radius 1 and infinite extent

Tags: metric-spaces

I have a question and I'm not exactly sure if I'm on the right track.  It isn't homework, just a curiosity I'm following:

Consider a right circular cylinder with fixed radius of 1.  This is parameterized by $\phi = [cos(\theta), sin(\theta), z] = \phi(\theta,z)$.  I want to define the metric (tensor?) on the cylinder as a manifold.  I believe I'm doing something wrong here but I can't figure out what.  If I understand it correctly, the metric is:

$g = J^T J$

And the Jacobian is:

$$
\left[
\matrix
{
-sin(\theta)&0 \\
cos(\theta)&0 \\
0&1    
}
\right]
$$

Then the metric is just $g = I_{2x2}$.  However, from another answer, it seems that this should be a 3x3 matrix.  Does it have something to do with the fact that I want the metric on the manifold itself, without embedding it into Euclidean space?  Or am I just totally off base?

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the formula for the metric and substitute $r=1$:
$$
J=\frac {\partial (x,y,z)}{\partial (r,\theta,z)}=\begin{pmatrix} \cos {\theta} & \sin {\theta} & 0 \\ -r\sin {\theta} & r\cos {\theta} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end {pmatrix}
$$
Then you will get the euclidean metric:
$$
g=\begin {pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end {pmatrix}
$$

Comment: I'm still a bit uncertain.  If I understand it correctly, a curve defined on my cylinder is parameterized by only two variables, $\theta$ and $z$.  For instance, a helix on the cylinder may be given as $r(\theta(t),z(t)) = [2\pi t, t]$.  The 3x3 metric won't work here.  I'm not sure what mistake I've made, though, since I agree with you as well...

Comment: I should also mention that using my 2x2 metric and determining the arc length of that helix on the interval $t \in [0,1]$, I do in fact get the correct answer of $4\pi^2 + 1$, which is the identical answer to considering the helix in Euclidean space $r(t) = [cos(2 \pi t), sin(2 \pi t), t]$.  So perhaps it does matter that I've chosen not to embed the cylinder in $R^3$?